# Find the absolute maximum and absolute minimum values of f on the given interval. $f(x) = \ln(x^2 + 7x + 14), [−4, 1]$

Tags: calculus

I got that the absolute maximum is $\ln(22)$ but I  can't seem to figure out the absolute minimum. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Hint: you need to make $x^2+7x+14$ as small as possible.

Comment: Hint: $ln x$ is an increasing function on it's domain. This means that the larger the input, the larger the value of $ln$. The smaller the input, the smaller the output. So you have to find the minimum possible input from the given domain. In other words, you have to find the minimum of that quadratic

Comment: How would I go about findidng the minimum of the quadratic?

Comment: The minimum of a quadratic is, graphically, at its vertex. Does $\frac{-b}{2a}$ ring any bells? (Otherwise, you could use calculus, but why do so if you don't have to?)

Comment: So the absolute minimum value is -7/2?

Comment: The $x$ value of the absolute minimum value is $\frac{-7}{2}$; however, absolute minimum/maximum values refer to the $y$ value.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated in the comments on the question, this is really just about minimizing $x^2+7x+14$. However, I'll type it out following the general process for these kinds of problems so you can see how it's done for functions that can't so easily be identified as increasing on their domains.

First, differentiate (by the chain rule):
\begin{align}
f'(x) = \dfrac{1}{x^2+7x+14}\times(2x+7)
\end{align}

Now, we need to set the derivative equal to $0$. So, $2x+7 = 0 \implies x = \tfrac{-7}{2}$.

Now, we compare this point and the end points to see which point gives us the minimum value.

- $f(-4) = \ln((-4)^2 + 7(-4) + 14) = \ln(2)$
- $f(-3.5) = \ln((-3.5)^2 + 7(-3.5) + 14) = \ln(1.75)$
- $f(1) = \ln((1)^2 + 7(1) + 14) = \ln(22)$

$\ln(1.75) < \ln(2) < \ln(22)$, so our minimum value is $\boxed{f(-3.5) = \ln(1.75)}$.

Comment: Thank you so much man. You are a hero among men. I'll be sure to give you a check.

Comment: @user136146 You are very welcome. It's really much easier to simply notice that this function is increasing across its domain and therefore try to minimize the argument. If you'll notice, that's really what I'm doing here. We end up setting $(x^2+7x+14)'=0$ with this method, which is exactly how we would do it if we were simply trying to minimize the quadratic alone. Or you can remember $\tfrac{-b}{2a}$. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the fact that $\ln$ is a one-one function to find the global max and min without usin calculus. here is how you do this. look at the quadratic $$y = x^2 + 7x + 14, -4 \le x \le 1. $$ the axis of symmetry is $x = -7/2.$ to find the global max and min of $y$ you need to look at the there points $-4, -7/2, $ and $1$.  the values are $2, 1.75, 22$  so we know that absolute max of $y$ is $22$ and occurs at $x = 1$ and abs min is $1.75$ and it occurs at $x = -7/2.$  therefore 
$$ \ln(1.75) \le \ln(x^2 + 7x + 14) \le \ln 22 \text{ for } -4 \le x \le 1.$$

Comment: One might note that "completing the square" gives us $ \ (x \ + \ \frac{7}{2})^2 \ + \ \frac{7}{4} \ \ , $ so the function  $ \ \ln(x^2 + 7x + 14) \ $ is defined for all real numbers.  Had the function been, say, $ \ \ln(x^2 + 7x + 12) \ $ , an absolute minimum would not exist.